# Adding a product field to cart summary in views

Tags: 7, views, commerce

I have a product image and product description as fields in the product entity. I want to add them to the cart summary displayed in the checkout, specifically it's the view "Shopping cart summary"

I added a relationship to the view: (Line items referenced by commerce_line_items) Commerce Line item: Product

And I added the two fields to the view.

When I preview it with an order number it works perfectly. the 2 fields are displayed as expected. But on the checkout page, the cart summary is blank...

What am I missing? How can i possibly debug this situation?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested, I found the answer here: https://drupalcommerce.org/discussions/1128/product-image-cart-form

It is a permissions issue. The solution was to enable the permission "view any product of any type" for anonymous users.